# Big O Notation Time Question

Tags: big-o

We have 3 functions with big o notations:

```
Func A: O(n)
Func B: O(n^2)
Func C: O(2^n)
```

If these functions does n proccesses in 10 seconds, how much time need to proccess 2 * n processes for each functions ? Also if you explain why i will be happy.

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you start by telling us what you think the answer is?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add the "homework" tag to it. Also, if you are having trouble, don't just ask your homework question and expect some to do it for you. Explain what you tried and where you are hung up or confused.

Comment: @Russel, Ben Lee this is my midterm question and i answered A = 20sec, B = 40sec, C = 40sec. Now i wondering about know true answers. Thanks

Comment: A and B are correct. 2^n complexity is pretty unusual, but I think the answer is not 40.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, you really can't tell with only one data point. By way of example, a simplistic answer for the first one would be "twice as long", 20 seconds, since O(n) means the time complexity rises directly proportional to the input parameter.

However, that fails to take into account that the big-O is usually simplified to show only the highest effect. The actual time taken may well be proportional to `n` plus a constant 5 - in other words, there's a constant 5 second set-up time that doesn't depend on `n` at all, then half a second per `n` after that.

That would mean the time take would be `15` seconds rather than `20`. And, for the other cases mentioned it's even worse since O(n<sup>2</sup>) may actually be proportional to `n^2 + 52n + 7` which means you would need *three* data points, assuming you even *know* all the components of the equation. It could even be something hideous like:

```
                  1      12
n^2 + 52*n + 7 + --- + ------
                  n    47*n^5
```

which would still technically be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

If they *are* simplistic equation (which is likely for homework), then you just need to put together the equations and then plug in 2n wherever you have n, then re-do the equation in terms of the original:

```
Complexity  Equation     Double N     Time Multiplier
----------  --------   -------------  ---------------
O(n)        t = n      t = 2n               2
O(n^2)      t = n^2    t = (2n)^2
                         = 4 * n^2          4
O(2^n)      t = 2^n    t = 2^(2n)
                         = 2^n * 2^n        2^n
                                            (i.e., depends on
                                                  original n)
```

So., the answers I would have given would have been:

- `(A)` 20 seconds;
- `(B)` 40 seconds; and
- `(C)` 10 x 2<sup>n</sup> seconds.

Comment: For 2^n, given you know that 2^n=10, then 2^n*2^n=10*10=100. Same answer I got using logarithms, but much simpler :)

Comment: And your TimeMultiplier should say: 2*t, 4*t, t^2, where t is original time.

Comment: @Iain, you're making the mistake here that 2^n = 10: it doesn't (well, it may, but it's not required). Those equations I used were just to show the ratio, _not_ the actual time values. It's quite possible that n could be 1 for the ten-second figure in which case it would be twenty seconds for 2n, not a hundred seconds.

Comment: @paxdiablo - maybe I'm reading the question wrong, because I still don't get it. Why is it not t^2? Because 2^n*2^n = (2^n)^2 = t^2. That is how you did the others, ie 4*n^2=4*t, and 2*n = 2*t. T is time, and is your time multplier.

Comment: @Iain, consider the first one assuming that the _actual_ relationship between time and input variable is `t=5n` (still O(n)) so that n=2 gives you your 10 seconds. Doubling `n` there gives you `t=5*2n` which is still a multiplier of 2 on the original time. Same for O(n^2), it's a constant multiplier. O(2^n) is not a simple multiplier like that, the multiplier depends on the original value of `n` (not `t`, since that's not necessarily 2^n but may be a value _dependant_ on that).

Comment: The one thing drummed into me in high school physics was "always check the units". Multiplying time by _time_ gives you seconds^2 which cannot be a duration. Multiplying time by a unitless value (like 2^n) will preserve its nature,

Comment: Your right, I'll fix up my answer with the mistake I made. Interestingly, while the units I ended up with is a smell, when I do the formula correctly the units are ok, but I am left with an unknown (the processing rate of items/second)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint

`Func A` is your base measure that takes 1 unit of time to complete.  In this problem, your unit of time is 10 seconds.  So `O(2*n) = 2*O(n) = 2 * Units = 2 * 10 sec = 20 sec`.

Just plug `2*n` into the `n^2` and `2^n` functions to get

```
  O((2*n)^2) = O(2^2 * n^2) = O(4 * n^2)
  O(2^(2*n)) = O((2^2)^n)   = O(4^n)
```

Now just figure out how many time units each represents and multiply by 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

A: 2 times as much

B: 4 times as much

C: 2^n times as much

?

time depends on n now

given time is 10 seconds and n also 10, this makes 20, 40 and 1024 seconds respectively :)

but if n is 1, it will be 20, 40 and 40...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: C is 10*2^n, I made a mistake in my answer. I'll leave it below but here is the mistake:

The real formula includes the processing rate, which I left out in my original answer. The processing rate falls away in the first two, but it doesn't in C.

```
2^n/p=10 (where p is the processing rate of units/second)
2^n=10*p
y=2^(n*2)/p
y=(2^n)^2/p
y=(10*p)^2/p
y=100*p^2/p
y=100*p (so we need to know the processing rate. If we know n, then we know the processing rate)
```

The units are fine above, as we have seconds^2/seconds = seconds.

**Original Answer**:

A: 20
B: 40
C: 100
The existing answers already explain A and B. Regarding the C equation, if my mathematics serve me correctly....

Part 1: What does n equal

```
2^n=10
log(2^n)=log(10)
n*log(2)=log(10)
n=log(10)/log(2)
```

Part 2: Now replace n with 2*n

```
x = 2^(2*n) 
x = 2^(2*log(10)/log(2)) 
x = 100 (thanks excel: =2^(2*LOG(10)/LOG(2)))
```

Still I haven't used [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) in 6 years, so please be forgiving if I'm wrong.

**EDIT**: Found a simpler way.

```
Given t is orginal time, and y is the new time.
t=2^n
y=2^(n*2)
y=(2^n)^2
y=t^2
y=10^2
y=100
```